# prevent search engines indexing depending on domain

Tags: nameserver, indexing, search-engine

We have a dedicated server with a hosting company with a couple of dozens of webs in it. It happens that the nameservers (EG: ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com) ip's are coincident with some client webs, let's say webclient1.com and webclient2.com

Problem is that for a certain searches in google, some results are showing up like ns1.domain.com/result instead of webclient1.com/result which is pretty wrong and annoying for our clients. Actually if you type in the browser ns1.domain.com or ns2.domain.com it will load some pageclients instead.

Is there any way to prevent google to track those results only in case the robots are coming to check ns domains? It may be not correct to ask this as well, but why is it happening? is it a result of a bad server configuration? I'm pretty new on these matters, so thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS configuration error, although it is hard to be certain from what little you have said. The content you want indexed is indexed but using the wrong (although working) URLs, and none of the content that you want to remain hidden is indexed, so robots do not seem to be the problem.

Presumably you do not want to publish the details here, so check your DNS (forward and reverse). Check also that links within your site use names and not hard-coded IP addresses in URLs.

A separate question is whether it is wise to use the same public IP addresses for name servers and web servers, and another is whether your hosting company's load balancer can help by separating the two types of traffic to different private IP addresses.